# Why does `finally: return 42` clear an uncaught exception?

Tags: python, exception, try-finally

Today this interesting piece of python code was posted [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/577724814103687168).

```
def f():
    try:
        raise KeyError
    finally:
        return 42


g = f()
```

When executing it, `f()` returns `42` and there's no exception bubbling up the stack as I'd expect. When replacing the `return 42` with e.g. as `pass` statement, the exception propagates outside the function as expected.

However, I wonder why that's not the case when using `return`. After all, there's still an uncaught exception.

Does this mean that a python function can either `raise` or `return` but a `return` will automatically clear an exception?